# Ordering list of items by two criteria

Tags: optimization, distance-functions, decision-theory

I have a list of items with two scores: scoreA and scoreB. To be more specific they represent the average of a list of accuracy scores and their maximum. Both of the scores range from 0 to 100%. I'm searching for methods to order the list of items by a balance of the two scores. The idea is to weight them differently but for simplicity let's consider equal weights. In that case, the top items of the list will have high scores for both but we do not want to rank very unbalanced items higher than more balanced ones. Example:

```
       ScoreA    ScoreB
Item1:  95%        70%
Item2:  60%        90% 
Item3   50%        60%
Item4:  75%        10%
```

I guess that the key here is using some kind of distance measure. Since both of the scores are going to be from 0 to 100% or 0 to 1, then we can just translated both scoreA and scoreB to x and y coordinates and calculate the distance to the (1,1) coordinate which will be the maximum. After that, we just have to order by the least distance. I want to know if this is correct or there are some other methods I can use.

Comment: If you value the two scores equally, how about using the average of the two; if not, then an appropriate weighted average?

Comment: Not the same purpose. (0.50,0.50) is a much better score than (0.90,0.20) even if the sum of the second is greater than the former. If you calculate the distance of the two points to (1,1) the distance is shorter for (0.50,0.50)

Comment: Then maybe you should give more detail on what the scores mean to you. Hard to guess that.

Comment: Yes. I wanted to keep it general but I will edit the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the answer will really depend on what exactly your ultimate objective is, which isn't clear in your question. However, what you describe makes me think of the [harmonic mean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_mean) as a possible solution. $$H(a,b)=\frac{2}{\tfrac{1}{a}+\tfrac{1}{b}}=\frac{2ab}{a+b}$$ In general, for two scores with a constant sum, the harmonic mean will become greater as the two scores become closer together. For the case of scores $A = \{0.50, 0.55, 0.50 ... 0.90\} $ consider the values of $B$ which give 1) equal (arithmetic) mean and 2) equal harmonic mean

[image]

Comment: But in this case, the sum of A and B has to be one?. This is not my case. I've edited the question to include this

Comment: Nope, the sum can be anything. See the second table of values with equal harmonic variance.

Comment: Yes. It's very clear in the second table. Observations with lower means have the same harmonic mean as higher ones just because of that "balance" concept. Just out of curiosity. Is the distance approach I posted in the original question valid?

Comment: Any approach can be valid depending on your objective. Perhaps the euclidian distance to point (1,1) has some real interpretation for the problem that make sit preferable. Otherwise, the preferred approach is whatever delivers the best results, so I'd encourage you to try both methods.